# how Login to a website using c# and read the contents of the logged in webpage (stream)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know if its possible at all for a website developed using asp.net , and, if so, could someone please give me a few pointers on how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean classic ASP or ASP.Net?

Comment: hi DOK .. its ASP.NET : apologies for not being clear .. Ill edit the post now

Comment: @HelloWorld_Always: No need to put the language in the question, we have tags for such an occasion. ;-)

Comment: you could have users redirect to your site, login, and then you send an authorization token back to the requesting site. or, you have them post the results of the form directly to your site, and you return whether or not it was successful and their user info. need more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is “login API”, according to you?

Comment: im sorry again for not being precise . the edited question is exactly what i want to do ..

Comment: Check my edited answer below.

Comment: Define "read the contents of a page - streamed" - this isn't clear. From a web app - or login from a desktop app to a website and then read the contents via a direct code request (not browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you can do this .If you are doing it with ASP.NET I would suggest you web-services. People using API can pass username and encoded password over network .Share a secret key with the client for encoding passwords.

This might help http://blogs.sitepoint.com/single-sign-web-service-asp-net/ .

By passing a username and a hashed password of the user to method u can authenticate. The method queries the database to see if a row exists that contains both the username and the password. If a row is found, the user is authenticated, return true. Otherwise, we've been given incorrect credentials, and a false is returned.

If you need to return a stream you can build the stream by reading some file Using File.IO StreamReader and return it as a response.

Comment: When you said API I assume you mean you want a third party to authenticate to your website.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of a third party website, you may want to use a `WebClient` class which will permit to fetch webpages and keep cookies in a `CookieContainer` class.

By making different web requests you will be able to POST (authentication) forms or even open HTTP stream for media elements such as videos. It's a bit hard to parse HTML but it's doable.

You just need to think as a web browser.

By the way, don't forget not to scrap elements under copyright.